# In VB.NET Query on what to do when field is empty

Tags: vb.net, linq

What I have is a form behind a login and I want to pull in a value from our database for the NameField IF that value exists, otherwise leave it blank for the user to fill in.

So I have the following if statement which works IF there is a value in our database for AliasName:

```
        If _NameID <> Guid.Empty Then
            Name.Text = (From c In _Data.CONSTITUENTs
                                  Where c.ID = _NameID
                                  Select c.KEYNAME).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
            NameField.Text = (From atc In _Data.CODEs
                               Join a In _Data.AliasName On atc.ID Equals a.CODEID
                               Where atc.DESCRIPTION = "Default Name" AndAlso a.CONSTITUENTID = _NameID
                               Select a.NAME).FirstOrDefault().ToString()

        End If
```

What I now need to know is how to add an if statement to read if there is a value that exists in the AliasName field and the description matches "Default Name", and if so, use that value, otherwise, allow the user to enter their own value.

Right now it is pulling in the value when it exists, but erroring out the page when it does not.

Comment: Instead of trying to do it in one line, get the `FirstorDefault`, check for Nothing and use the default in that case.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Yeah I would think with the "Select a.Name" you should be good to just use .FirstOrDefault() and drop the .ToString() to get the expected results.

Comment: The removal of the .ToString() has returned the proper results and I'm no long seeing the error!  Thank-you for pointing that out!